# Error while sending QUERY packet. Magento 2 (2.1.5)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo

I'm trying to install the Magento 2 (2.1.5) on web server with CLI. but its is giving error

> [Exception] 
>   Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=34 in
>   /home/cocaine/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 228

I searched for the solution and all the solution is that increase the

> max_allowed_packet

First max_allowed_packet was 33MB but now i increased it to 512MB. But it's still giving me same error with different  PID.

CLI commands used to install Magento is

```
 magento setup:install --base-url=http://www.example.com \
 --db-host=localhost --db-name=db_name --db-user=db_admin --db-password=db_admin_password \
--admin-firstname=User  --admin-lastname=Magento --admin-email=admin@demo.com \
 --admin-user=admin_site --admin-password=admin_password --language=en_US \
--currency=INR --timezone=Asia/Kolkata --cleanup-database \
--session-save=db  --use-rewrites=1
```

Comment: make sure that value is changed

Comment: value of max_allowed_packet is changed. i checked it with SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Comment: is it present in php -m ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.What is php -m?. are you asking max_allowed_packet is present in php.ini file?

Comment: i mean maybe you cli use another config

Comment: show output of php -m in console

Comment: [PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imap
intl
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
suhosin
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend Guard Loader
zip
zlib
This is what i get by php -m on
[Zend Modules]
Zend Guard Loader
the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured)
This is what i get form php -m  command on server

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet value from your database configuration.

increase wait_timeout = XX to wait_timeout=180

Also, Change at least max_allowed_packet  = 512M